# Should list array elements be wrapped in xml representation?

Tags: java, xml

When creating a REST/XML webservice, and showing `List` objects: should the list elements be wrapped in a list element (eg `<persons>`), or should the response just list multiple `<person>` elements?

Example:

```
@XmlElement
private List<Person> persons;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    //...
}
```

Nested:

```
<rsp>
 <persons>
   <person>
     <name />
     <age />
   </person>
   <person>
    ...
   </person>
 </persons>
</rsp>
```

Flat:

```
<rsp>
   <person>
     <name />
     <age />
   </person>
   <person>
    ...
   </person>
</rsp>
```

Comment: Easier to use the list element so that you can traverse the paths easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll be apt to wrap the list in a parent element like `persons`. Two reasons for doing that:

As pointed out by @tanyehzheng, it allows adding attributes to the list like size.

With a wrapped style, it allows your response object `<rsp>` to be extensible to include other objects, in a cleaner fashion. Say tomorrow we wish to add data like below (this is just an example)

```
<rsp>
   <persons>
      <person>
       <name />
       <age />
      </person>
      <person>
       ...
      </person>
  </persons>
  <performanceInfo>
    <processingTime>122</processingTime>
  </performanceInfo>
</rsp>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would have wrapped it nested. Because it's more natural to add metadata like the size of the list

```
<persons size="42">
  <person>
    ...
  </person>
  <person>
    ...
  </person>
  .
  .
  .
<persons>
```

Answer (score 2):

When it comes right down to it, I would go through a few well known RESTFUL interfaces ( or at least interfaces used in your services environment ).  I would try to be as consistent as possible so your ecosystem of developers will have an intuitive start to understanding the API that you have designed.

From a technical perspective, I suspect that the wrapping of the element can make parsing or application coding more efficient.  Of course, there are the benefits of being able to provide attributes for the list itself (as 
tanyehzheng has already stated ).

Personally, I prefer the wrapped XML as well, but not for any technical reasons.  In XML editors/viewers, the  element can be collapsed and thus the response can be made more terse for humans.

Answer (score 1):

The `XmlElement` annotation is from the JAXB 2 specification for representing XML as Java classes/object graphs and vice versa. JAXB 2 binding rules are essentially based on mapping XML Schema definitions to Java classes. Elements that can occur multiple times via the XML Schema `maxOccurs="unbounded"` attribute, or a `maxOccurs` value greater than 1 within their containing type are by default represented as a list property (a `Java.util.List` of element items), or alternatively, and less commonly, as an indexed property with accessors such as `getProp(int index)` for `Prop` an element name.

So I would say unless specific requirements dictate otherwise, I would *not* use wrapper elements for the typical use case you describe. One caveat, though, is that you'll want Java member names in plural form whereas in XML you'll want the singular form. In your example, you'll want to avoid an XML element Name `Persons` for a Java method signature such as `List<Person> getPersons()`, and you can use the `@XmlElement(Name = Person)` annotation to get you an XML element in the singular form instead.

There's a larger discussion behind your question: XML, like SGML (the common superset of XML and HTML), is a *text* format for representing semistructured data (it was initially designed to supersede HTML, but that didn't work out). As such, the kind of data that SGML/XML was designed for, by definition, isn't represented adequately in a Java component model seeking to tightly map Java classes/objects to markup elements at all. Instead, a DOM representation, or another representation for sequential acccess to markup elements where the document order of elements *of different types* among each other is honored, is arguably a more natural fit. In fact, JAXB 1 had more complex mapping rules which could roundtrip document order of elements. But it turned out that for the comparatively simple data-oriented use cases which XML is used for most of the time this wasn't helpful. Hence, JAXB 2 was designed to more easily capture data-oriented use case like yours.